# Inject Shellcode - program running and need to inject hexcode from maybe python

Tags: python, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

So I have a vulnerable program which is to be exploited using buffer overflow. After analysis I have all the relevant values(buffer size, the address to be injected ,etc )
The issue is that I need to automate the inputs given to it.

Precisely here's what happens :

1. the program asks for a normal input -- (No vulnerability present here)
2. It asks for a second input -- this is to be injected with the shellcode

I have tried sending the input from the file (by writing it with the payload say python -c 'print '.. blah blah), but the file somehow sends the ascii representation and messes up with the desired input

Things I have tried : Wrote a shell script like this :

```
echo -e "<first input>\r";
python -c 'print "A"*100 + "<shell code>"+"<ret>";
```

after this I send this file as an input :   `$ ./vuln < File`

Is there anyway that I send the output from python when the program is prompting for the second input ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm), a program used to automate interactions with programs that expose text terminal interfaces.

The script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn programUnderTest
expect firstPrompt
send firstInput
expect secondPrompt
send secondInput
```